# Add group to user in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created 3 groups 1. Staff, 2. Admin, 3. Operational Manager and assigned permission. Now whenever I wanted to add  new user I wanted to show the choice field of the group and able to select the group.

As per the framework the User and Groups have many-to-many relations and I am trying to implement nested serializer. And as per documentation to add nested data I need to implement `create` or `update` method in the serializer but here I am not getting the choice field in group and the data is null.

GroupSerializer:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = ('name',)
```

UserSerializers:

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name','address','contact', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'branch', 'groups')

def create(self, validated_data):
    groups_data = validated_data.pop('groups')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for group_data in groups_data:
        Group.objects.create(user=user, **group_data)
    return user
```

when I wanted to make a post request I am getting :

```
{
"first_name": "",
"last_name": "",
"address": "",
"contact": null,
"email": "",
"date_of_birth": null,
"branch": null,
"groups": []
}
```

here groups fields are empty. 
If I try to make a post request it says

```
{
"groups": [
    "This field is required."
]
}
```

Edit : Solved

I removed `GroupSerializer` because `User` model has many-to-many relation with `Group` so we don't need to explicitly specify `Group` object

```
# class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
#     class Meta:
#         model = Group
#         fields = ('name',)


 class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username','first_name', 'last_name','address','contact', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'branch', 'groups')

def create(self, validated_data):
    groups_data = validated_data.pop('groups')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for group_data in groups_data:
        # Group.objects.create(user=user, **group_data)
        user.groups.add(group_data)
    return user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PrimarykeyRelatedField` and provide id of groups that you want to add in a list. like below:

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Group.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'contact', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'branch', 'groups')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        groups_data = validated_data.pop('groups')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for group_data in groups_data:
            Group.objects.create(user=user, **group_data)
        return user

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        r = super(UserSerializers, self).to_representation(instance)
        r.update({
        'groups': GroupSerializer(many=True).to_representation(instance.groups)
        })
        return r
```

So just provide list of groups like this: `"groups": [1,2,3]`

and you should also override `to_representation` method if you want to have serialized json result of each group in response.